# Net::FTP Perl module hangs

Tags: redhat, ldap, perl

So, I'm running Perl 5.8.8 on a RHEL5.2 system. I recently moved the LDAP source for authentication, and now I'm having issues with `Net::FTP`.

Authentication works with the new LDAP source perfectly.

Now, as a specific non-root user on the system, if I execute "`use Net::FTP`", the script hangs and begins filling up the messages log with:

```
Mar 28 12:10:05 serverx perl: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://ldapserver.domain.net: Can't contact LDAP server
Mar 28 12:10:05 serverx perl: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server (sleeping 64 seconds)...
```

If I, as root, execute "`use Net::FTP`", no problems.

I have since cleared the `nscd` caches (hosts, passwd, group), and done everything short of rebooting the server (which really isn't an option).

Does anyone have any idea why the heck this is happening?

Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I feel stupid - but thanks for strace to help me figure out the issue.

Not that this would happen to anyone else, but the file I was using for the trusted root CAs for OpenLDAP and the Pam module was set to mode 0400 and owned by root. After I fixed the permissions, viola.

Comment: could you accept your answer so this question does not hang in "unanswered"?